# Using api route without authentication in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-routing

I want to simply return some JSON data from a controller, therefore I thought to use api route.

MyController.php:

```
public function data()
{
    //return json string
}
```

That controller is supposed to be used by both api and web routes, depending on my needs.

api.php:

```
Route::get('data', 'MyController@data');
```

When I visit the path: `/api/data` it redirects me to `/home`.

However, when I change my route to the following it works:

```
Route::get('data', function() {
    //return json string
});
```

I am not sure if it is related to authentication. I am not binding any middleware to my route as you can see.

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: How are you trying to access that route, via your browser or something like Postman?

Comment: I am simply trying to access it from browser: `http://localhost/api/data`

Comment: Do you have some middleware in your constructor?

Comment: Which constructor you mean exactly?

Comment: What is the output of `php artisan route:list --path=api`, does your `/data` route contain anything other than `api` in the `middleware` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a middleware defined in your controller, do this

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['yourMethodName']]);
```

Comment: Where can I find the defined middlewares in my controller?

Comment: It should be in _contruct(){ } constructor.
something like this 
    public function __construct()

Comment: Oh right. I see it now. I feel stupid not have noticed it before. Thanks a lot!